# A hash collision just happened

Tags: hash, ethereum, solidity, hash-collision

A smart contract address (0xc3ba5050ec45990f76474163c5ba673c244aaeca) generated in the Remix IDE on my local machine matches with an EOA (0xc3ba5050ec45990f76474163c5ba673c244aaeca) on Rinkeby in a transaction that happened 18 days ago. What is the chance for that?

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xccded101b78665f405658764e7b24270050c1ed3687ebc65353ae53a46dbb831

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was the deployer address the same (of course on different networks)?

Comment: @PetrHejda Not really. One is for a smart contract on my local machine, and the other is an EOA address on Rinkeby.

Comment: You are likely to misunderstand things, as it is not theoretically possible.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa That is what I thought too. I'm saving evidence and will post and share it. By the way, do you know how to export Remix IDE console history?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Besides, I have to say it is theoretically possible, but numerically very unlikely.

Comment: Since the size is 40 hexits = 20 bytes = 160 bit, the chance to find such a match is `1.0/2^80` or 8.2 * 10^{-25} due to birthday paradox. So extremely small.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sure, it is known to be an extremely small value. But give this has happened, should I make a story out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following four links are html codes of the contents in the Remix console. They match the graphs above. The address 0xc3ba5050ec45990f76474163c5ba673c244aaeca can be found in all four texts files corresponding to four functions call in my local Remix IDE. They cannot be the EOA on Rinkeby, which kinda work as proofs of this hash collision.

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmege6nX8pni9GfwEorncqKeRFNEMFytyj9A4zfq3QJHBn?filename=text.txt

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXGbazceni8pKyXzmXHFeDfT2FneQzwRTogDkaHTAhMG7?filename=text2.txt

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcdjgDiGEc48i4uQ6upZ9HMMv1gAC42JquAaf3Jd9V224?filename=text3.txt

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTCuxQRoQ6ZRWNRw2LyhsDwernuujaNXFi5KTZkXhVnjs?filename=text4.txt

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a hash collision. First of all, a smart-contract address is just like any address on the outside. You can send tokens to a smart contract before it's even deployed because the address is calculated in a deterministic way from the deployer address and the nonce.

Secondly, the addresses used in Remix IDE for local deployment can be used to deploy a contract on mainnet - why not? The private keys are published [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/d13fea7e8429436de6622d855bf75688c664a956/libs/remix-simulator/src/methods/accounts.ts).